# How to disable the minor ticks of log-plot in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is a simple plot:

[image]

1) How to disable the ticks?
2) How to reduce their number?

Here is a sample code:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

x = [5e-05, 5e-06, 5e-07, 5e-08, 5e-09, 5e-10]
y = [-13, 14, 100, 120, 105, 93]

def myfunc(x,p):
    sl,yt,yb,ec=p    
    y = yb + (yt-yb)/(1+np.power(10, sl*(np.log10(x)-np.log10(ec))))
    return y

xp = np.power(10, np.linspace(np.log10(min(x)/10), np.log10(max(x)*10), 100))

pxp=myfunc(xp, [1,100,0,1e-6])
subplot(111,axisbg="#dfdfdf")
plt.plot(x, y, '.', xp, pxp, 'g-', linewidth=1)   
plt.xscale('log')

plt.grid(True,ls="-", linewidth=0.4, color="#ffffff", alpha=0.5)


plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Which produces:
[image]

Comment: For more control: [how to turn on minor ticks only on y axis matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711202/how-to-turn-on-minor-ticks-only-on-y-axis-matplotlib)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
plt.minorticks_off()
```

Turns em off!

To change the number of them/position them, you can use the `subsx` parameter. like this:

```
plt.xscale('log', subsx=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=tick#matplotlib.pyplot.xscale):

> subsx/subsy: Where to place the subticks between each major tick.
>   Should be a sequence of integers. For example, in a log10 scale: [2,
>   3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>
> will place 8 logarithmically spaced minor ticks between each major
>   tick.

Comment: Well, this is one reason that I can not use the matplotlib's documentation nicely. One huge help file without separation. I still cannot find the documentation for this function.

Many thanks!

Comment: @Danial Tz - yeah the volume of documentation is nuts!

Answer (score 36):

Calling `plt.minorticks_off()` will apply this to the current axis.  (The function is actually a wrapper to `gca().minorticks_off()`.)

You can also apply this to an individual axis in the same way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.minorticks_off()
```

Comment: This answer is the only one that mentions the OO approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np


x = [5e-05, 5e-06, 5e-07, 5e-08, 5e-09, 5e-10]
y = [-13, 14, 100, 120, 105, 93]

def myfunc(x,p):
    sl,yt,yb,ec=p    
    y = yb + (yt-yb)/(1+np.power(10, sl*(np.log10(x)-np.log10(ec))))
    return y

xp = np.power(10, np.linspace(np.log10(min(x)/10), np.log10(max(x)*10), 100))

pxp=myfunc(xp, [1,100,0,1e-6])
ax=subplot(111,axisbg="#dfdfdf")
plt.plot(x, y, '.', xp, pxp, 'g-', linewidth=1)   
plt.xscale('log')
plt.grid(True,ls="-", linewidth=0.4, color="#ffffff", alpha=0.5)
plt.minorticks_off() # turns off minor ticks

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable ticks on one axis only, you can do it by

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
```

I am not sure why there is no more convenient way for disabling ticks on a single axis.

EDIT: Now I found a similar answer to a related question with a more complete answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56447047/516066