# how to turn on minor ticks only on y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, yticks

How can I turn the minor ticks only on y axis on a linear vs linear plot?

When I use the function `minor_ticks_on` to turn minor ticks on, they appear on both x and y axis.

Comment: found it .. `plt.minorticks_on()`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', bottom=False)
```

Comment: Using this I get a `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning` for using `bottom='off'`. Apparently `ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',bottom=False)` should be used instead.

Comment: I still had the problem that the minor tick labels were showing. You can turn them off with `labelbottom=False`.

Comment: The method does not seem to work if you at the same time want to specify location or labels of major ticks. Then, use the alternative solution given in this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56447047/516066

Answer (score 35):

Here's another way I found in the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

a = np.arange(100)
ml = MultipleLocator(5)
plt.plot(a)
plt.axes().yaxis.set_minor_locator(ml)
plt.show()
```

This will place minor ticks on *only* the y-axis, since minor ticks are off by default.

Comment: I would recommend using `plt.axes().yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))` instead of first initializing `ml`. If you reuse `ml` this can lead to horrible mistakes which are hard to find. Also the more natural choice could be `AutoMinorLocator` unless something specific is requested.

Answer (score 23):

To clarify the procedure of @emad's answer, the steps to show minor ticks at default locations are:

1. Turn on minor ticks for an axes object, so locations are initialized as Matplotlib sees fit.
2. Turn off minor ticks that are not desired.

A minimal example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2])

# Currently, there are no minor ticks,
#   so trying to make them visible would have no effect
ax.yaxis.get_ticklocs(minor=True)     # []

# Initialize minor ticks
ax.minorticks_on()

# Now minor ticks exist and are turned on for both axes

# Turn off x-axis minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='minor', bottom=False)
```

### Alternative Method

Alternatively, we can get minor ticks at default locations using `AutoMinorLocator`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tck

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2])

ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.AutoMinorLocator())
```

### Result

Either way, the resulting plot has minor ticks on the y-axis only.

[image: plot with minor ticks on y-axis only]

Answer (score 22):

To set minor ticks at custom locations:

```
ax.set_xticks([0, 10, 20, 30], minor=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you only want minor ticks on the actual y-axis, rather than on both the left and right-hand sides of the graph, you can follow the `plt.axes().yaxis.set_minor_locator(ml)` with `plt.axes().yaxis.set_tick_params(which='minor', right = 'off')`, like so:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

a = np.arange(100)
ml = MultipleLocator(5)
plt.plot(a)
plt.axes().yaxis.set_minor_locator(ml)
plt.axes().yaxis.set_tick_params(which='minor', right = 'off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

The following snippets should help:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(#))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(#))

# refers to the desired interval between minor ticks.
```