# How to add smaller ticks between main ticks in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to make some plots, and I was wondering if you have any idea about adding smaller ticks in between the main ones, like in this image:

[image]

Comment: The larger ticks are called major ticks, the smaller ones are called minor ticks. Those notions should allow you to search for soltutions.

Comment: Let me get you started by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711202/how-to-turn-on-minor-ticks-only-on-y-axis-matplotlib) and [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html)

Comment: thank you! problem solved. 

I just set ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor')

Comment: @jorafb you can answer your own question and accept your answer so people know it's solved :)