# How to replace ticks in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to change the ticks intervals on a figure, which looks like that:

[image]

I use this:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(1945, 2016, 10))
```

However, what I finally get is:

[image]

As you can see, I can't take out the smaller ticks. I tried this line:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=0)
```

But without success, since it show this:

[image]

I lost the ticks I would like to plot.

To plot, my code is:

```
for row, plot in enumerate(toplot):
for col, country in enumerate(countries):
    ax = axes[row][col]
    (dx[(plot, country)]
     .plot(ax=ax, c=color)
     )
```

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you could try to use `ax.tick_params(which='both', axis='x', length=0)`. See the `Axes.tick_params` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) for more information.

Comment: Please include your source data and the whole code you use so far. We have no time to "recreate" the source data from your plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is disable the "minor ticks". [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html) you can find the official documentation about it, and [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781077/how-to-disable-the-minor-ticks-of-log-plot-in-matplotlib) on stackoverflow about it. I did not try it myself bu just adding `ax.minorticks_off()` should do the trick !

Comment: Thanks! I did not realise there was two different types of ticks